# Forcing Wordpress/server to show new image with same file name

Tags: wordpress

I uploaded an image yesterday, but had to swap it out with a new one with the same file name and path due to the client using that path in various places (email signature, and other locations).  I've deleted and re-uploaded the new image several times but it's still showing the old image.  I'm doing this from FTP since I created the upload year/month folder manually, and it isn't appearing in the Wordpress Media Library.

I've cleared the server cache, restarted the server, cleared my browser cache, but it's still showing the old image.  It's been over a day now since swapping out the old image for the new.

Is there a deeper way of completely removing the old image and replacing it?  Perhaps from the database rather than uploads folder?  SOMETHING is hanging onto it, and I need to clear that out so it shows the new version.

Comment: Are you certain the FTP is updating the file? Does the file's timestamp change when you upload the replacement? If you delete the image and then upload it directly to the media folder without using the Media Library it will not show up as this is not populated using only the filesystem but also _wp_posts_ and _wp_postmeta_ tables in the database

Comment: I think you can do it by **regenerate thumbnails**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I ended up finding a plugin that was able to get it working.  This is the one I used:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-library-plus/#folders%20and%20images%20added%20to%20the%20site%20by%20ftp%20are%20not%20showing%20up%20in%20media%20library%20folders

After placing it in the folder from the plugin page into the folder I created in FTP, it showed the correct image.